# Rails4 -> Change param name for select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that is being build from a `Product` model. One of the form elements is a select list that has qty/price information, the form is being posted to a `Cart` model:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: add_cart_path, method: :post do |f| %>
...
<%= f.select :prices, price_list %>
```

The `price_list` helper builds an option list with the quantity for `option value` eg:

```
<option value="25">25 for $75.00</option>
```

On post I receive the param values as `"product"=>{"prices"=>"25"}` as expected. I would to prefer to receive this `"product"=>{"qty"=>"25"}` since it's the qty I'm passing and not the price. Is there any way to rename the parameter?

Comment: Why are you using `:prices` if you want to pass `:qty`? Why not just `f.select :qty`?

Comment: Because qty does not exist in the Product model. I load the Price / Qty combination from embedded documents (using mongoid). It makes sense to display the :prices but pass the :qty to cart. At least I think that it does, maybe I'm complicating this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to use [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag):

```
select_tag "product['qty']", ...
```